# Customise BootstrapDateTimePickerInput

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, widget

This is my registration form. The ridiculous date format allows me to differentiate between my custom made format and more generic ones.

[image]

**models.py**

```
 class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        d_o_b = models.DateField(default=timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=6570))
```

6570 is 18 * 365

**forms.py**

```
 widgets = {'d_o_b': BootstrapDateTimePickerInput(format='%d/%d/%m/%m/%m/%m/%Y', attrs={'class':'datepicker-start'})}
```

When I change the date, the date format changes to an American style one.

[image]

When I change the date, I want my custom made formatting to remain. And I also want to stop users being able to select dates pre 2000.

**boostrap_datetimepicker.html**

This was the default code (minus the date format which I modified).

```
  {% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %}

  <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}" data-toggle="datetimepicker">  

    <div style='background-color:blue' class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>

  </div>

</div>


<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}").datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/DD/MM/MMM/YYYY/',
      
    });
  });
</script>
```

I thought the function  `widget.datetimepicker_id` would run every time you chose a date. I thought you used this function to determine how your date could appear on the screen. But the function only seems to have any effect first time you load the page and only when d_o_b has a default value.

And if you have (a)

```
widgets = {'d_o_b': BootstrapDateTimePickerInput(format='%d/%d/%m/%m/%m/%m/%Y', attrs={'class':'datepicker-start'})}
```

as oppose to (b)

```
widgets = {'d_o_b': BootstrapDateTimePickerInput()}
```

then the function `widget.datetimepicker_id` also seems to have no effect.

I changed the code to

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}").datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/DD/MM/MMM/YYYY/',
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "2005:2012"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Unfortunately I was still able to pick pre 2005 dates, post 2012 dates and change the month.

In normal circumstances I would want the user to be able to change the month, but I was trying to see what (if any) code was having an impact on my widget.

In forms.py I have `attrs={'class':'datepicker-start'})`. I added the below code to boostrap_datetimepicker.html, but it seemed to have no impact on the dates the user could select.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker-start" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "2005:2012",
      // more options can also be included

    });
$(".datepicker-end" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1900:2012",

    });
  });
</script>
```

I changed `datepicker` to `datetimepicker` and that seemed to have no impact either.

I also tried changing `data-target="#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}"` to `data-target="datepicker-start"`. That did not seem to have any impact either.

**widgets.py**

```
from django.forms import DateTimeInput

class BootstrapDateTimePickerInput(DateTimeInput):
    template_name = 'widgets/bootstrap_datetimepicker.html'

def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
    datetimepicker_id = 'datetimepicker_{name}'.format(name=name)
    if attrs is None:
        attrs = dict()
    attrs['data-target'] = '#{id}'.format(id=datetimepicker_id)
    # attrs['data-target'] = '#{id}'.format(id=datetimepicker_id)

    attrs['class'] = 'form-control datetimepicker-input'
    context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
    context['widget']['datetimepicker_id'] = datetimepicker_id
    return context
```

I have no idea if I am remotely close to achieving my goals. I am now just very confused. I would be grateful if someone could offer me some guidance.

I looked at the developer tool. The element I am interested in had the id id_d_o_b. So I changed my jQuery to the below but it had no effect.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#id_d_o_b").datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/DD/MM/MMM/YYYY/',
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "2005:2012"
      
    });
  });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: "#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}" is looking for the '#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}' id, literally that string, it is not parsing it. You can validate that by trying to console.log("#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}") and seeing what if anything appears. I think what's going on here is that the JS is not finding your datepicker because that Id doesn't exist, so your formatting is not getting applied. This is definitely a JS problem, not a backend one.

Comment: I looked at the developer tool. The element I am interested in had the id id_d_o_b. So I changed my jQuery to the below but it had no effect.

    $("#id_d_o_b").datetimepicker({